# Oracle - Date Format

Tags: oracle

I need your assistance with converting Oracle dates.

I have a column that stores dates like this `20150731 00:00:34.220`. However, I would like to show the column like this `20150731` but when I run a simple select statement to test output I get the following error.

```
select TO_DATE('20150731 00:00:34.550','YYYYMMDD')
from dual
```

Error

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: Hi guys - data type of the column is VARCHAR2.

Comment: "that **stores** dates like this ..." if it does store data like that it is not a date column, but you may be confusing the default display of dates to be how they are stored - which isn't true. real dates in Oracle are stored as sets of integers representing different time units. That numeric data is transformed into a human readable format by db defaults or by deliberate action via to_char(). If the data IS stored as a varchar then please say that explicitly.

Comment: then all you need is **substr(that_column_here, 1, 8)** unless I have missed something

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help guys. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query

```
select TO_DATE('20150731 00:00:34.550','YYYYMMDD')
from dual
```

leads to error

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

because you pass string with length 22 characters, but at the same time you pass date format with 8 characters, which obviously doesn't correspond to string. You should write the query as

```
select to_timestamp('20150731 00:00:34.550','yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss.ff3')
  from dual
```

As for your table, since you have `varchar2` column with dates, you have to take care about table content. Query requires exect matching of the source string and date format.
If you want to show only date without time and you don't need to process this string as date, you can make just

```
select substr('20150731 00:00:34.550', 1, 8)
  from dual
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type of the column?  If it is `DATE` (as it *should* be) then not it is not stored in the format you say.  It is stored in an internal binary format.  You would/should use the to_char function to DISPLAY it in whatever format you choose.  If you do not use the to_char function, it will be displayed in the format specified by `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, which can be specified at several locations.

As for your example, you passed a string format of yyyymmd hh:mi:ss.fff', but you provided a description mask of only `YYYYMMDD`.  It doesn't know what to do with time component.  In addition to that when you `SELECT TO_DATE`, oracle also has to do an implied `TO_CHAR` to convert it back to a string for display purposes.

In addition, you provided your to_date with a character string that included fractions of seconds.  A `DATE` data type only resolves to seconds.  If you need fractional seconds, you need to use `TIMESTAMP`, not `DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Is that being stored in an Oracle datetime column? If not, you may have to do some manipulation to get it into a DD-MON-YYYY format. If it is being stored as a text string you could use `SUBSTR( Date_field, Start_Position, Length)` to get the first 8 characters. check out this link [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a varchar and you need a date output:

```
select TO_DATE(substr('20150731 00:00:34.550', 1, 8),'YYYYMMDD') from dual
```

If it's in a date format and you need a string output:

```
select to_char(your_column, 'YYYYMMDD') from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption that you're not trying to change the value in the column, and are just trying to show it in the `YYYYMMDD` format -

As mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name, you'll just need to convert it to a character string.  In this example I used systimestamp as my date:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD') FROM DUAL
```

Result:

```
20160121
```

That should give you the `YYYYMMDD` format you want to display.